# Magento - Import pending orders through excel or csv files

Tags: magento

Is it possible to import pending  orders through an Excel or CSV file in Magento? If yes, how can I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to be an existing and dedicated [module](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/bolasevich/extension/2063/dataflow-batch-import-+-export-orders-to-csv--xml)
 for this, I used Google to find this. There will probably be more!

Answer (score -2):

you can do it,but it is to hard.
that use cart & checkou object to finish.
1.analyze data from xls
2.add product to cart
3.setting billing address & shipping address
4.checkout